# How to retrieve one text string from one column which contains two text string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let us consider below a table.

Input Table

```
Emp_ID     EmployeeName 
1           Mark hos
2           jhon carte
3           Mike hold   
4           Mark Danny
5           Stacy hodegf
```

How to retrieve Output like below

```
Output Table
Mark
jhon
Mike
Mark
Stacy
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you already tried in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Left` with `CharIndex`:

First, Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Emp_ID int,
    EmployeeName varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @T (Emp_Id, EmployeeName ) VALUES
(1, 'Mark hos'),
(2, 'jhon carte'),
(3, 'Mike hold'),  
(4, 'Mark Danny'),
(5, 'Stacy hodegf'),
(6, 'NoSpaceHere')
```

The query:

```
SELECT Emp_Id, LEFT(EmployeeName, CHARINDEX(' ', EmployeeName +' ')) As FirstName
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Emp_Id  FirstName
1       Mark 
2       jhon 
3       Mike 
4       Mark 
5       Stacy 
6       NoSpaceHere
```

Please note that I've added a trailing space to the `EmployeeName` in the `charindex` function to return the entire `EmployeeName` in case there is no space there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using substring() and charindex() function

```
select substring(EmployeeName,0,charindex(' ',EmployeeName))
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX as the other answers suggest, or you can take a look at STRING_SPLIT which is probably a better solution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What makes you think `string_split` would be a better solution?

Comment: How would it be cleaner? I would love to see a cleaner solution to this particular problem using string_split.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TempEmp
(
    Emp_ID          INT,
    EmployeeName    VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #TempEmp
SELECT 1,'Mark hos' UNION
SELECT 2,'jhon carte' UNION
SELECT 3,'Mike hold' UNION  
SELECT 4,'Mark Danny' UNION
SELECT 5,'Stacy hodegf'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(EmployeeName, 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', EmployeeName)>0 THEN CHARINDEX(' ', EmployeeName) - 1 ELSE LEN(EmployeeName) END ) AS Firstname FROM #TempEmp
```